# How to remove several items from an array of JSON objects in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, javascript-objects

I have a JSON object that I want to remove a series of items from:

```
const addressNonRequired = ["addr_linkid_usr", "addr_created", "addr_updated"]
```

I know I can use the 'delete' method, but how would I use the above array to do the same:

```
// remove non-required data
addressesFound.forEach(row => (
  // delete row.addr_linkid_usr,
  // delete row.addr_created,
  // delete row.addr_updated
  addressNonRequired.forEach(item => (
    delete row[item];
  ));
));
```

I've tried several ways to get this to work, not sure if I'm looking at it the right way .... ?

Example of array provided:

```
[
  {
    "addr_id": "41d86d46-8b19-4f4e-be03-f9915ef4947b",
    "addr_type": "postal",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": false,
    "addr_international": false,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": null
  },
  {
    "addr_id": "b18c2ca6-29cf-4114-9067-b37fd3394638",
    "addr_type": "residential",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": true,
    "addr_international": true,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": "string"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "addr_id": "41d86d46-8b19-4f4e-be03-f9915ef4947b",
    "addr_type": "postal",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": false,
    "addr_international": false,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": null
  },
  {
    "addr_id": "b18c2ca6-29cf-4114-9067-b37fd3394638",
    "addr_type": "residential",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": true,
    "addr_international": true,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": "string"
  }
]
```

Comment: Added example ```addressesFound```

Comment: Your example fails with: ```Argument of type 'Address' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the `addressesFound` array, and in each object iterate over the keys of that object, compare if that key exists in `addressNonRequired` array and remove it, if applicable.

```js
var addressesFound = [{
    "addr_id": "41d86d46-8b19-4f4e-be03-f9915ef4947b",
    "addr_type": "postal",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": false,
    "addr_international": false,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": null
  },
  {
    "addr_id": "b18c2ca6-29cf-4114-9067-b37fd3394638",
    "addr_type": "residential",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": true,
    "addr_international": true,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": "string"
  }
];

const addressNonRequired = ["addr_linkid_usr", "addr_created", "addr_updated"];

var updatedAddresses = addressesFound.map(function(address) {
    Object.keys(address).forEach(function(key) { // For each address object, iterate over the keys
    if (addressNonRequired.includes(key)) {
      delete address[key]; // Check if the key is present in the addressNonRequired array. Delete if present
    }
  });
  return address;
});

console.log(updatedAddresses);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this very often when filtering an object or an array of objects.

I usually have these in my `helpers.ts` file. They also make sure that the keys you are filtering does exist in the object and it also has autocomplete.

```js
export function except<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T, keys: Array<K>) {
    const copy = { ...data };
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (key in copy) {
            delete copy[key];
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

export function exceptMany<T, K extends keyof T>(data: Array<T>, keys: Array<K>) {
    return [...data].map((item) => except(item, keys));
}
```

Then to filter an array of objects, we do:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "addr_id": "41d86d46-8b19-4f4e-be03-f9915ef4947b",
    "addr_type": "postal",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": false,
    "addr_international": false,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": null
  },
  {
    "addr_id": "b18c2ca6-29cf-4114-9067-b37fd3394638",
    "addr_type": "residential",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": true,
    "addr_international": true,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": "string"
  }
];

const results = exceptMany(data, ['addr_linkid_usr', 'addr_created', 'addr_updated']);
```

Filtering keys from just one object is also possible:

```js
const single = {
    "addr_id": "41d86d46-8b19-4f4e-be03-f9915ef4947b",
    "addr_type": "postal",
    "addr_linkid_usr": "user1",
    "addr_created": "2021-03-10",
    "addr_updated": "",
    "addr_active": true,
    "addr_postal_as_residential": false,
    "addr_international": false,
    "addr_autocomplete_id": null
};

const filteredSingle = except(single, ['addr_linkid_usr', 'addr_created', 'addr_updated']);
```